# Dynamically select a destination queue for JMSProducer in Micronaut

Tags: java, jms, micronaut, activemq-artemis

I have a Java Micronaut app that connects to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue and sends some messages. The configuration is very basic and it lets Micronaut handle the actual logic:

```java
@JMSProducer(CONNECTION_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME) 
public interface DemoProducer {

    @Queue("demo_queue")   
    void send(@MessageBody String body);  
}
```

The problem now is that I want to be able to dynamically specify the destination queue name based on the situation through a parameter or something.

Is this achievable in Micronaut without having to define a separate method for each queue name or to custom implement the whole connection and sending functionality?

Comment: Looking at the documentation and the code in GitHub I don't see how what you want is possible. FWIW, the JMS API is pretty straight-forward so it should be pretty simple to do this yourself.